# usage of the word "modest IQ"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I came across the expression "modest IQ" in a book.

> Drawing on groundbreaking brain and behavioral research, he shows the factors at work when people of high IQ flounder and those of modest IQ do surprisingly well.

Which does this "modest" mean, average, or low?

Comment: We could guess, but it would help if you gave the entire paragraph. It would also be nice if you included what you found when you looked up the word _modest_. See [_Details, Please..._](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more helpful tips.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The whole sentence is as follows:  Drawing on groundbreaking brain and behavioral research, he shows the factors at work when people of high IQ flounder and those of modest IQ do surprisingly well.

Comment: I updated your question to provide the complete context you gave in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If something has a *modest* price, it doesn't cost much. It's price is not high.

It is not a precise term.  We know only that it doesn't mean *high*.  It is *probably* in the middle range.

If something is a *modest success* it is sufficiently successful. Nothing to brag about but nothing to be disheartened about either, not a failure.